# $.post cannot find file path.Am i missing something?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to make instant search (google like) for my page.When a user write a food name it must search variables from database and return if there are matches(which i will make with php).Php code isn't causing problems for now,but java is other thing.It displays [this](http://prntscr.com/dqmv67) error when i enter any letter.I tried everything from scratch for like 5 times,and every time i get to java it starts with this error.My Food-Groups-BG page is [this](http://prntscr.com/dqmw23)and it is in my main theme folder where are all other .php page files.I don't know why it cannot find the page.. Please help ;/
Btw I am working in wordpress.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $("#food_search").keyup(function(event){
  var search_term =$(this).val();
  $.post("/Food-Groups-BG.php",{search_term: search_term},function(data)
   {
    $("#food_search_result").html(data);
   })
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Търсене на храни: <input type="text" name="food_search" id="food_search"></p>
<div id="food_search_result"></div>
```

Comment: How sure are you that the `/Food-Groups-BG.php` is where it should be? i.e. in the document root.

Comment: Well i read that if file is in main directory it must be only with / and the file name,i don't really know how java gets main directory without declaring it..I am still a newb

Comment: Well, just a heads up: you are confusing JavaScript with Java. Two very different languages with very different use cases. Your web root (main folder) is usually the one containing wp-admin, wp-includes and wp-content. So, if you want to use a URL like /filename.php, it needs to be in that folder.

Comment: Yap it is right there,i downloaded server logs to see the requests,and i saw that it was getting other pages from /wp-content/themes/yuuta/Food-Groups-BG.php. So i changed it and now it gives me Internal server error 500... :D
http://prntscr.com/dqvzq5

Comment: Edot:I also noticed that there is error_log file in my folder template which is created when i changed my file path and it says: 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_header() in (folder path here)

Comment: Well, it seems you *do* want to use the wordpress framework, because you seem to be using `get_header()` in your file. Please, please, please try and build this using `wp_ajax_` actions.

Comment: I am using it just for clear code reading ... 
<div id="header-container"><?php include('header.php');?></div> i done it with php... Just using WP for short things for time to time,i don't really wanna learn WP commands.Sorry for being stubborn,but i don't wanna WP <3 thanks for your time

Comment: Well, by including `header.php`, you are including that command (`get_header()`) which needs the WP framework. So, in order to not get the error, don't include `header.php`.

Answer (score 0):

When working with wordpress I would advise to use admin-ajax.php. That is:

`add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_food_groups_bg, function(){
//whatever contents are in your ajax file. also, you can use the wordpress framework
die();
});`

and call the function with `/wp-admin/admin_ajax.php?action=food_groups_bg`

Comment: I will try it,is there a way to do it without wordpress the ajax.Thanks!

Comment: Sure, but why not use wordpress when you are using a wordpress site? I would very much advise you to use the wordpress framework, as raw database access usually ends up as a BIG security hole.

Comment: You are totally right mate,but i really wanna learn to code without WP.That is my first website and i know it won't be really a professional one ;) . I got 1 guys which can secure it atleast some part of it.